# Original Facebook Share Button With Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to catch the callback response of Facebook share button event.
my code is

```
    <button class="my_own" type="button" onclick="share();">Share on Facebook</button>

    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'YOUR_FB_APP_ID',
                xfbml: true,
                cookie: true,
                version: 'v2.6'
            });
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        });

function share() {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'Example Title',
                link: 'http://www.example.com',
                picture: 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg',
                description: 'example desc'
            }, function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('Thank you for sharing!');
                } else {
                    alert('You have cancelled the share.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This above method is working fine with custom Facebook share button and I am able to catch the callback function.

But I want to do it with native Facebook share button for example with this code below

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.example.com" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

I have done a lot of research on this, and it seems impossible because many said Facebook doesn't allow this functionality on original share button, but then I came across this WordPress plugin called 'Social Locker, they have done this with original Facebook share button, you can check it on this below URL.

http://demo.byonepress.com/premium/sl-wp/example/use-cases/

The catch the successful share event and load the ajax to show the data. Can anyone help me out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to know if someone shared?

Comment: What that Social Locker plugin offers is against Facebook’s Platform Policy. You are not allowed to require a like or share before you show content.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I just gave it for a example. Actually I want to use it for downloading my free PDF.

Comment: I have done this with a little css hack.

Comment: @ArbazAbid Have you found a solution?